# Responsive Image Gallery - Grid issue with thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I found an example of a responsive image gallery and I want to implement it on my website: https://mobirise.com/bootstrap-gallery/#gallery1-0

I'm using Mobirise to create a gallery, but I don't know how to make this gallery look like in this sample - first two images in the column stacked on top of each other and the second column just one picture having a height equal to first two pictures.

Resizing the image in an HTML editor results in overlapping other thumbnails.

```css
.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.mbr-gallery .icon-focus,
.mbr-gallery .icon-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 32px);
  left: calc(50% - 24px);
  font-family: 'MobiriseIcons' !important;
  font-size: 3rem !important;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
  z-index: 5;
}

.mbr-gallery .icon-focus::before {
  content: '\e96b';
}

.mbr-gallery .icon-video::before {
  content: '\e95c';
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item>div:hover .icon-focus,
.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item>div:hover .icon-video {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
  transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item>div:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item>div {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item .icon {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 69px;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transition: .2s opacity ease-in-out;
  width: 69px;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item .icon::after,
.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item .icon::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 69px;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: 34.5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item .icon::after {
  width: 69px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 34.5px;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item>div:hover .icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item>div:hover::before {
  opacity: .9;
}

.mbr-gallery .mbr-gallery-item>div:hover .mbr-gallery-title {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="mbr-gallery mbr-slider-carousel cid-r82PWHW6OG" id="gallery1-0">

  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <!-- Filter -->
      <!-- Gallery -->
      <div class="mbr-gallery-row">
        <div class="mbr-gallery-layout-default">
          <div>
            <div>
              <div class="mbr-gallery-item mbr-gallery-item--p1" data-video-url="false" data-tags="Creative">
                <div href="#lb-gallery1-0" data-slide-to="0" data-toggle="modal"><img src="assets/images/gallery02.jpg" alt="" title=""><span class="icon-focus"></span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="mbr-gallery-item mbr-gallery-item--p1" data-video-url="false" data-tags="Animated">
                <div href="#lb-gallery1-0" data-slide-to="1" data-toggle="modal"><img src="assets/images/gallery03.jpg" alt="" title=""><span class="icon-focus"></span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="mbr-gallery-item mbr-gallery-item--p1" data-video-url="false" data-tags="Awesome">
                <div href="#lb-gallery1-0" data-slide-to="2" data-toggle="modal"><img src="assets/images/gallery04.jpg" alt="" title=""><span class="icon-focus"></span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="mbr-gallery-item mbr-gallery-item--p1" data-video-url="false" data-tags="Awesome">
                <div href="#lb-gallery1-0" data-slide-to="3" data-toggle="modal"><img src="assets/images/gallery05.jpg" alt="" title=""><span class="icon-focus"></span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="mbr-gallery-item mbr-gallery-item--p1" data-video-url="false" data-tags="Responsive">
                <div href="#lb-gallery1-0" data-slide-to="4" data-toggle="modal"><img src="assets/images/gallery06.jpg" alt="" title=""><span class="icon-focus"></span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="mbr-gallery-item mbr-gallery-item--p1" data-video-url="false" data-tags="Animated">
                <div href="#lb-gallery1-0" data-slide-to="5" data-toggle="modal"><img src="assets/images/gallery07.jpg" alt="" title=""><span class="icon-focus"></span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Lightbox -->
      <div data-app-prevent-settings="" class="mbr-slider modal fade carousel slide" tabindex="-1" data-keyboard="true" data-interval="false" id="lb-gallery1-0">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active"><img src="assets/images/gallery02.jpg" alt="responsive image gallery" title="item 1"></div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="assets/images/gallery03.jpg" alt="responsive image gallery bootstrap" title="item 2"></div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="assets/images/gallery04.jpg" alt="css responsive image gallery" title="item 3"></div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="assets/images/gallery05.jpg" alt="html image gallery code" title="item 4"></div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="assets/images/gallery06.jpg" alt="image gallery html css" title="item 5"></div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img src="assets/images/gallery07.jpg" alt="responsive image grid" title="item 6"></div>
              </div><a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev" href="#lb-gallery1-0"><span class="mbri-left mbr-iconfont" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next"
                role="button" data-slide="next" href="#lb-gallery1-0"><span class="mbri-right mbr-iconfont" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a><a class="close" href="#" role="button" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="sr-only">Close</span></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written this code in codepen, hope that it's what you were looking for!
Let me know if you want further informations.

Code in description is the one that I've used in the second column image to fill the container and prevent to stretch.

Link: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmPaQN)

```
.fill{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```